# SQL select data from 4 tables

Tags: mysql, select

I want to select data from 4 tables. I have:

```
transactions: no_transactions, date, quantity, no_tank, id_cards, no_terminal
tanks: no_tank, type , price, temperature
terminals: no_terminal, location
cards: id_card , no_card , id_person
people: id_person , first_name, last_name
```

I want to select all no_transactions, date, quantity from transactions,
type , price, temperature from tanks where tansk.no_tank = transactions.no_tank 
location from terminals where terminals.no_terminal = transactions.no_terminal 
first_name, last_name from people where people.id_person = cards.id_person(but it must be cards.id_card = transactions.id_cards).

How can I do it?

I trying this:

```
SELECT no_transactions, date, quantity FROM transactions
UNION
SELECT type , price, temperature FROM tanks WHERE tansk.no_tank = transactions.no_tank
UNION
SELECT location FROM terminals WHERE terminals.no_terminal = transactions.no_terminal
UNION
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM people WHERE people.id_person=(select id_person where cards.id_card = transactions.id_cards)
```

but it doesn't work :(
can anyone help ?

Comment: Hint: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using below query

```
select no_transactions, date, quantity from transactions, type , price,
temperature,location,first_name, last_name from transactions AS TR
INNER JOIN tanks AS TK on (TR.no_tank=TK.no_tank) 
INNER JOIN terminals As TM on (TR.no_terminal=TM.no_terminal) 
INNER JOIN cards CD on (TR.id_card=CD.id_card)
INNER JOIN people P on (CD.id_person=P.id_person)
where your condition if you need.
```